# Contractions: Are “I would’ve” and “I’d have” both equally permissible?

Tags: orthography, contractions, register, contraction-vs-full-form

Instead of *“I **would have** done something”*, are both of these versions ok?

1. I **would’ve** done something.
2. I’**d have** done something.

Comment: You can also do *I'd've*

Comment: Pretty much all the contractions of _I would have_ are pronounced /'aydə/, same as _Ida_. Likewise /'yudə, 'hidə, 'ʃidə, 'widə, 'ðedə/. _It would have_ comes out /'ɪtədə/, with both /t/ and /d/ reducible to a tap [ɾ] at will. You can see why English has difficulty with spelling contractions -- the orthography just doesn't have the resources necessary.

Comment: @JohnLawler interesting, I definitely have a /v/ with the double contraction unless I'm in my most informal register and even then saying it feels more like I'm making fun of pronunciations and doesn't come off that naturally. It's *almost* a syllabic /v/ but I definitely transfer the /d/ to the syllable, but I don't have a (to me anyways) perceptible vowel.

Comment: The point is that there are thousands of ways to modify the phonemes involved under fast speech rules, so worrying about one of two or three spelling conventions -- none of which cover everything -- is not worth the effort. If you don't want to worry about it, write it any way you want.

Answer (score 4):

Grammatically speaking, all the three constructs are correct. The non-contracted first one is more formal. The choice between the other two can be made only by [euphonic](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/euphonic) considerations, i.e. whichever sounds nicer or is easier to pronounce given the surrounding words.

The very colloquial *I'd've* is not unheard of either.

Comment: First, I don’t know that I would call this a matter of being “grammatically speaking”; spelling is not part of grammar. In any event, *I’d’ve* is pretty much the ***most*** that anybody ever actually says without having their feet held to the fire, and as John Lawler observes, it quite often rhymes with *Lida* from the song *Lida Rose*.  So it isn’t in any way “very colloquial” for someone to ***say*** *I’d’ve*; rather, it is perfectly normal, common, accepted, and nearly expected.  What is not so expected is the orthography. But that changes nothing about what people actually say.

Comment: @tchrist In Australia _I'd've_ is unheard of except in British television. I've never heard an Australian native English speaker use both contractions at the same time. We almost always say _I would've_. That being said, _I'd have_ is also incredibly uncommon, as it naturally tends to become _I'd've_; it's hard to clearly separate _I'd_ from _have_ unless _have_ is stressed. "I'd **have** to say that, wouldn't I?" However, in my example I don't believe _have_ can be contracted.